# Updating multiple rows with different data with a specific id using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to update `ApproveStatus` of rows with `RequestId=2` where the `goodsId = 4` is rejected and `goodsId=1` is approved.

My question is how to do that using Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core 2.2.

This is what I have done so far:

```
// model contain "approve" and "reject" strings and requestId which came from view
public IActionResult ApproveList(List<ApprovedGoodsByAdminAssistVM> model)  
{
    // I got the requestId from model
    var id = model.Select(s => s.RequestId).FirstOrDefault(); 

    // Filtered the two record with RequestId=2 from the table 
    var goodsList = context.RequestGoodsBrand
                           .Where(x => x.RequestId == id).ToList(); 
}
```

What to do next?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with “where the goodsId=4 is rejected and goodsId=1 is approved”? A single row cannot have two different values for the same property/column. In your table, there are two separate rows, one with GoodsID=4 and one with GoodsID=1. What do you want to do to each? Also, what is your `ApprovedGoodsByAdminAssistVM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IActionResult ApproveList(List<ApprovedGoodsByAdminAssistVM> model)
    {
        var requestId = model.Select(x => x.RequestId).FirstOrDefault();
        var approvedItems = model
            .Where(x => x.RequestId == requestId && x.ApproveStatus == 1)
            .Select(x => x.GoodsId).ToList();

        var rejectedItems = model
            .Where(x => x.RequestId == requestId && x.ApproveStatus == 0)
            .Select(x => x.GoodsId).ToList();

        var goodsToBeApproved = context.RequestGoodsBrand
            .Where(x => x.RequestId == requestId && approvedItems.Contains(x.GoodsId)).ToList();
        goodsToBeApproved.ForEach(x => x.IsApproved = 1);
        context.SaveChanges();
        var goodsToBeRejected = context.RequestGoodsBrand
                .Where(x => x.RequestId == requestId && rejectedItems.Contains(x.GoodsId)).ToList();
        goodsToBeRejected.ForEach(x => x.IsApproved = 0);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Json("Done!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, these changes could solve your issue.

```
public IActionResult ApproveList(List<ApprovedGoodsByAdminAssistVM> model)   
{
   var id = model.Select(s => s.RequestId).FirstOrDefault();  
   var goodsList = context.RequestGoodsBrand
      .Where(x => x.RequestId == id).ToList();  

   var rejectedItems = goodsList.Where(x => x.GoodsId == 4).ToList();
   var approvedItems = goodsList.Where(x => x.GoodsId == 1).ToList();

   foreach (var item in rejectedItems)
       item.ApproveStatus = "rejected";

   foreach (var item in approvedItems)
       item.ApproveStatus = "approved"

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Just instead of these magic words ('Rejected' , 'Approved'), you would better use an enum

Comment: But in this code nothing will be committed to database